# Run the last event in multiple consecutive events in javascript

Tags: javascript

How to apply the last event in multiple consecutive events?

For example: (I want my mainFunc() function to run only once and last call)

```
//leaflet map
map.on('moveend zoomend', function () {
    updateBoundaries();
});


let processing = false;
function updateBoundaries(){

    processing = true ;
    setTimeout(function () {

        if(processing == true){
           mainFunc();
           processing = false;
         }
    },3000);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember the previous timer handle and cancel it when you get a new call. Eventually, the events will stop, so the timer won't be cancelled, so your function will run.

```
let handle = 0;
function updateBoundaries(){
    clearTimeout(handle); // ***
    handle = setTimeout(mainFunc, 3000);
}
```

Re the line marked with `***`: It's absolutely fine to call `clearTimeout` with `0` the first time, the call is just ignored; and it's absolutely fine to call it with the handle of a timeout that has already run (which will happen when you get a stream of events, then they stop for three seconds so the timer runs, then you get another event). So there's no need to make that call conditional, or to clear `handle` when the timer runs. You *can* if you like:

```
// The handle logic here is completely unnecessary
let handle = 0;
function updateBoundaries(){
    if (handle) {
        clearTimeout(handle);
    }
    handle = setTimeout(function() {
        handle = 0;
        mainFunc();
    }, 3000);
}
```

...but it's completely unnecessary, as is guaranteed by the spec [here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-cleartimeout) and [here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#timer-initialisation-steps). (If you use Node.js, that spec doesn't apply, but it's still perfectly fine to do the above. Note that Node.js's timer handles are objects rather than numbers, but 0 still works [e.g., no error] for the first call.)